# Microsoft Word Document Presented as ASCII Text

Tags: text, ms-word

I have an SOAP API that is returning the name of a word document, and a tag that contains 3.5 MB of text that I have been told is the ASCII encoded version of the word document.

I sadly do not have many other details.  Has anyone ever seen anything like this, and have any ideas of how this would be converted back to a word document?

I've done much google searching and I'm not coming up with much.

I can't really include the string I'm getting as it is too big and contains company  proprietary information.

Comment: When you said it is ASCII encoded version, most likely it is base64 encoded  document.

Comment: Try pasting your tag file contents to https://www.base64decode.org/ and save the contents to a binary doc which will be your work document.